# how to set new properties in an array of objects explicitly

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a nested property and I'm trying to figure a clean way to replace it without using a bunch of slice and splice (currently what I'm using looking, I'm looking for a cleaner solution with or without lodash)

updating only `reproducible_counter: 0` to become `reproducible_counter: 1` within 
`id:0` and `urls.id 85`

```
data = [{
    id: 0,
    groupID: "65da6a",
    urls: [{
        id: 85,
        searchedurl: "https://www.yahoo.com",
        errorurl: "https://www.yahoo.com/error505",
        count: 1,
        reproducible: false,
        reproducible_counter: 0
      },
      {
        id: 84,
        searchedurl: "https://www.gmail.com",
        errorurl: "https://www.gmail.com/error404",
        count: 1,
        reproducible: false,
        reproducible_counter: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1
    groupID: "d4127e",
    urls: [{
      id: 3,
      searchedurl: "agwscc",
      errorurl: "xyqa",
      count: 1,
      reproducible: false,
      reproducible_counter: 0,
      resolved: null
    }]
  }
];
```

Comment: `looking for a cleaner solution` Can you post your current code?

Comment: You have two `id`s, one in the outer objects, and one in the inner objects (inside `urls`), which are you referring to? Just that single object whose `id` is 85?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ES6 `chain`:

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, groupID: "65da6a", urls: [{ id: 85, searchedurl: "https://www.yahoo.com", errorurl: "https://www.yahoo.com/error505", count: 1, reproducible: false, reproducible_counter: 0 }, { id: 84, searchedurl: "https://www.gmail.com", errorurl: "https://www.gmail.com/error404", count: 1, reproducible: false, reproducible_counter: 0 } ] }, { id: 1, groupID: "d4127e", urls: [{ id: 3, searchedurl: "agwscc", errorurl: "xyqa", count: 1, reproducible: false, reproducible_counter: 0, resolved: null }] } ];

var result = data
.find(({id}) => id === 0)
.urls
.find(({id}) => id === 85)
.reproducible_counter = 1

console.log(data[0].urls[0].reproducible_counter)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With lodash `_.chain`:

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, groupID: "65da6a", urls: [{ id: 85, searchedurl: "https://www.yahoo.com", errorurl: "https://www.yahoo.com/error505", count: 1, reproducible: false, reproducible_counter: 0 }, { id: 84, searchedurl: "https://www.gmail.com", errorurl: "https://www.gmail.com/error404", count: 1, reproducible: false, reproducible_counter: 0 } ] }, { id: 1, groupID: "d4127e", urls: [{ id: 3, searchedurl: "agwscc", errorurl: "xyqa", count: 1, reproducible: false, reproducible_counter: 0, resolved: null }] } ];

_.chain(data)
 .find({id: 0})
 .get('urls')
 .find({id: 85})
 .set('reproducible_counter', 1)
 .value()

console.log(_.get(data, '0.urls.0.reproducible_counter'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```
for(var index=0; index< data.length; index++){
   data[index].urls.filter(u => u.id === 85)[0].reproducible_counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot have a simpler one than this. We have to first match the outer id and then the inner id. Sorry if I get the question wrong. and the assumption is that the id is unique.

```
data.some(outer => {
  if (outer.id === 0) {
    outer.urls.some(inner => {
      if (inner.id === 85) {
        inner.reproducible_counter = 1;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"Clean" is subjective, but assuming ids are unique, one possible lodash solution is:

```
_.chain(data).find({id: 0}).get('urls').find({id: 85}).assign({reproducible_counter: 1}).value();
```

For example:

```js
data = [
      {
        id: 0,
        groupID: "65da6a",
        urls: [
          {
            id: 85,
            searchedurl: "https://www.yahoo.com",
            errorurl: "https://www.yahoo.com/error505",
            count: 1,
            reproducible: false,
            reproducible_counter: 0
          },
          {
            id: 84,
            searchedurl: "https://www.gmail.com",
            errorurl: "https://www.gmail.com/error404",
            count: 1,
            reproducible: false,
            reproducible_counter: 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 0,
        groupID: "d4127e",
        urls: [
          {
            id: 85,
            searchedurl: "agwscc",
            errorurl: "xyqa",
            count: 1,
            reproducible: false,
            reproducible_counter: 0,
            resolved: null
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

// Goal: updating only reproducible_counter: 0 to become reproducible_counter: 1 within  id:0 and urls.id 85
_.chain(data).find({id: 0}).get('urls').find({id: 85}).assign({reproducible_counter: 1}).value();
document.getElementById('result').innerText = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```